# Python script to read CAD data to find polygon extents

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, cad

I have Civil 3D 2012 with ArcGIS for AutoCAD 300. I want to read the extents of a polygon in the drawing. Feature Class in A4A300 = Boundaries, the CAD layer is PROP-BNDY, there is only one polygon on that layer since it is the perimeter of the site.
Do I have to convert the polygon to a temporary shapefile, read it, and then delete it? I will be using the boundary extents plus a constant in all directions to clip raster images. The process should not involve user input. I have 30 directories that I will be looping through, a drawing file in each directory and a polygon in each drawing. I have the python routines for creating a list of directories that have the *map.dwg files in them and I'm familiar with clipping the rasters, I just cannot find how to read the polygon extents in the dwg file.
Your help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: My first thought was to do what you have described (convert, read, delete).  I know you can create AutoCAD scripts, but i'm not sure if you can do what you would like to do in that scripting environment.  Maybe post that question [here](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/AutoCAD-2012/bd-p/529).

Comment: Is the polygon feature in Postgres, MSSQL, Oracle etc.?

Comment: Thanks for your input. I was able to find a work around but found out I was creating a monster! I was clipping MrSID files but had no format in which to save the clipped file that did not create HUGE files. I am working with very large images (4 inch pixels covering about 100 acresas the clipped version) and ended up with unruly tif or jpg files. SO I abandoned the idea of doing this process.

Answer (score 2):

As you have suggested you will have to convert the CAD polygon feature to a GIS feature class or feature layer, then you may use arcpy to get the geometry extent.

First, to make a temp/in-memory layer your could use [Make Feature Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000006p000000) function, see example code below:

```
polyCAD = "C:\\Temp\\xyz.dwg\\Polygon"
lyr = "Polygon_Layer"

# Process: Make Feature Layer using a expression
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(polyCAD, lyr, "\"Layer\" = 'PROP-BNDY'")
```

Alterntivley, if you want the temp layer to be converted to an actual temp file you could use [Feature Class to Feature Class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001200000020000000).

For both cases you can then get the layer extent using the [getExtent()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s300000008000000) method:

```
lyr.getExtent()
```

Comment: After i use the getExtent method, i got an Error!
lyr.getExtent()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'getExtent'
Thanks, Geog

Comment: Can you post your code as an edit to your question?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert dwg file to feature class, then get the extent of the polygon, using the code below:

```
arcpy.CADToGeodatabase_conversion(path_dwg, output_gdb, "fc" , 200)
extent = arcpy.da.SearchCursor( "fc" , ["SHAPE@"   ] , "\"Layer\" = 'PROP-BNDY'").next()[0].extent
```